# Use If statement <header> CSS Variable change

Tags: php, css, monstra

I'm trying to use an `if` statement to change the `<header>` tag depending on if it's the homepage or another page.

I have tried:

```
<?php
function specific_bgpages() {
  if(is_home())        
    echo '<header>';
  elseif(is_page() )   
    echo '<header  class="bgpages">';
}
add_action('genesis_header', 'specific_bgpages);
?>
```

But it's not working.

I'am using the CMS Monstra editor. Not wordpress.

Comment: can you post code of is_home() & is_page() ?

Comment: You need to pass a page identifier (ID, name etc) into `is_page()` - see the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: @MADTerry you dont need the core of `is_home()` and `is_page()` - Thats are `Core functions`, see the WordPress-Codex.

Comment: @scrowler, see the docs - Thats **Optional**.

Comment: How you implement that? on the `header.php`, or what template?

Comment: Implement it at header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

============= SOLVED ===================

Not need any php code.

Monstra have ability to assign different "Templates" styles to pages

Duplicate you Index and Header Templates
(give other name for example header-clone and index-clone)

Go to the page you pretense with different style
 - > settings and assign the different style

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EttOo.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMy2f.png]

Thats all ;)

ps: not can post imgs yet mod please edit.

Answer (score 0):

Close the quote in specific_bgpages in add_action function

Change

```
add_action('genesis_header', 'specific_bgpages);
```

to

```
add_action('genesis_header', 'specific_bgpages');
```

Comment: Hi, I get blank page. Really not understand why not work :(. I'am using Monstra CMS (csm editor for php)

Comment: ok enable WP_DEBUG to true in wp-config.php file and see what error occurs in this page

Comment: try place open { and } for if and elseif condition...maybe it may cause trouble..

Comment: I'am getting the follow error (using the development mode):
<code>Message: Call to undefined function add_action()<code>

Comment: As per documentation use `Action::add('genesis_header', 'specific_bgpages');` see http://monstra.org/documentation/plugin-api

Comment: Thank you Tamil.<br> Have work. <br> But now my <header> not appear only the code between <header> :s What can be?

Comment: i think is_home() and is_page() is not available in monstra cms. please review it...

Comment: Can be, but I not find documentation of default values for loads.

Comment: It is possible the usage of code by specific Title of pages?

Comment: yes, you check `if( Page::slug() === 'something' ) { ... }`

Comment: I have try by adding the if( Page::slug() === 'Home' ), get blank page :s. What I can do wrong?

Comment: Tamil Selvan issue resolve, more easy yet, without need of php code. Monstra have ability to assign diferent "Templates" to pages :) - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ec2je7je6 and http://awesomescreenshot.com/0962je8hb7

Comment: Nice...Post the solutions in your question..it help others